# how to join two lists with their respective values

Tags: python, list

So I have two lists

```
a_List = [24.6781, 23.4512, 26.4623, 16.9619, 17.7685]
a_List2 = [3000.0, 500.0, 900.0, 900.0, 3000.0]
```

where I want the values of a_List2 to be connected to a_List to get a desired output of

```
1-3000 2-900 3-3000 4-500 5-900
```

Where position 3 has the largest values of a_List2 and position 4 has the smallest value of a_List2
basically connecting the two lists with their respective values while maintaining the correct indexes of a_List, keep in mind that the position of the values could differ.

the value 26.4623 is the highest value in a_List so it should be connected to the highest value in a_List2 which is 3000

the value 24.6781 is the second-highest so it should be connected to the second-highest value in a_List2 which is 3000

the value 23.4512 is the third-highest so it should be connected to the third-highest value in a_List2 which is 900

and so on.

then I need to print out the connected values from a_List2 in the correct order of indexes of a_List

```
        for i in range(routers):
            a_dict.update({max(a_list) : max(a_list2)})
            router_list.remove(max(a_list2))
            a_list.remove(max(a_list))
        for x in a_dict.values():
            other_count+=1
            print(str(other_count)+"-"+str(int(x)), end= " ")
a_dict = {}
routers = 5 since we have 5 routers in this particular case
```

which will give me the semi correct output of

```
1-3000 2-3000 3-900 4-900 5-500
```

but it doesn't keep the structure if a_List which is what I need
 [image: drawn example of what I want to achieve]

Also not allowed to use any built in python sort() function.

Comment: What about sorting both input?

Comment: I think you could try sorting both of your lists in descending order first. That would line them up for you.

Comment: I also just edited the question, I'm not allowed to use any built in sort function so that won't work

Comment: Implement your own sorting function

Comment: You can call `enumerate` on one of the lists to introduce an index. You will have an iterable of tuples. After you finish your algorithm, use the indexes to produce the desired order.

Comment: You should include initial `a_dict` and `routers` variables (or an example) to help answerers understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

## What I think you're asking

Given two lists of the same length, how can I sort one using the values of the other?  For example:

```
to_show = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
to_sort = [100, 200, -50, 700]
assert MAGIC() == ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']
```

## How to go about this

Indeed, you can get a sorted version of one list using the other very simply.  Let's use `sorted` since it doesn't modify anything in place, which is friendly.  There are many possible approaches, one might look like the below:

```
>>> [b for a, b in sorted(zip(to_sort, to_show))]
```

a "clever" version of this might look like:

```
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(to_sort, to_show)))[1]
('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')
```

## How this works

This does a couple of things, it first groups your two lists together using `zip`

```
>>> zip(to_sort, to_show)
[(100, 'a'), (200, 'b'), (-50, 'c'), (700, 'd')]
```

it next sorts those values.  Python sorts tuples based on the first, then the second, then the third, etc.  This means we sort first by `to_sort`, and would break ties based on `to_show` (no ties with our data).

```
>>> sorted(zip(to_sort, to_show))
[(-50, 'c'), (100, 'a'), (200, 'b'), (700, 'd')]
```

In our clever version we call `zip(* ...)` to "unzip" that data back into two lists:

```
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(to_sort, to_show)))
[(-50, 100, 200, 700), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')]
```

and grab the second list, `to_show` (now sorted) using a list index:

```
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(to_sort, to_show)))[1]
('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')
```

## Alternative approach using `key=`

```
>>> [v for i, v in sorted(enumerate(to_show), key=lambda i_v: to_sort[i_v[0]])]
['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']
```

You may prefer is to use the `key` keyword argument to `sort` or `sorted`.  The goal will be to say "when you sort item 1 of `to_show`, just look at `to_sort` instead".  To do this we will include the index, and then strip it out afterwards.

We use `enumerate` to give us the index with the value

```
>>> sorted(enumerate(to_show), key=lambda i_v: to_sort[i_v[0]])
[(2, 'c'), (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (3, 'd')]
```

and can then follow the same processing as above (`zip` or comprehension) to extract the value (this time the `0` index instead of the `1`).

Note that there is no function of the form below (i.e. ignoring indexes)

```
>>> sorted(to_show, key=magic(to_sort))
```

that can exist, a lookup from values in `to_show` to `to_sort` will have trouble with duplicate values in `to_show`.

Comment: All nice, but OP's requirement is to not use built-in `sort()` function. Guess, `sorted()` counts as well.

Comment: To be honest that requirement is a red herring that was added after my answer, and is completely separable.  To paraphrase `Dani Mesejo` above: "step 1 - write a sort function`.  This is a typical assignment question to see if the user can implement a sort without copy-pasting, since the implementation will be a few characters different in one line.